# How can I see the queries (SQL statements) that are generated when I modify or edit the records of a PostGIS table, inside QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis

This is the DB manager, and it shows only the history of the statements that were used, but it does not show the records of the modified data in a table.

How do I see the history of the statements made in the database when modifying records?

[image]

Comment: you need to do this on the postgres side (if configured) https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158846/show-log-of-the-sql-statements-that-qgis-generates-to-retrieve-data-from-postgis

Comment: gracias por todo lo revisare